# I got the getaway car stuck in GTA V. How do I complete the mission?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I think it's mission 36? After figuring out the trash truck, masks and the firefight, I'm taken back PRECISELY to where I parked the getaway car which happens to be in a place I can't move it out of.

The getaway car is indestructible once you call it in and the getaway car mission cannot be chosen to be replayed.

With the getaway car stuck the mission can't be completed so I can' t advance the main mission line.  What should I do?

Comment: Can you free it by ramming it with another vehicle?

Comment: Can you pull it out with a tow truck? Probably irritating to find a tow truck, but you usually have to park the getaway vehicle around where you would find one anyway..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are unable to destroy the car before the mission, and can't move it, you could try killing yourself when you destroy the garbage truck - if you fail a story mission often enough, you get the option to skip it.

Comment: to be exact : failed 3 times to enable "Skip Mission" option

Answer (score 4):

If there's absolutely no way to get the car unstuck, destroy it with a grenade before starting the mission. It should ask you to get another car before you can start the mission.